# Help finding a function given its derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have shown in a problem that $ f'(x) = -f (x) $ .  I can't seem to find any function that has this property.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: $f(x) = e^{-x}$?

Comment: And to get *all* solutions: $f(x)=ae^{-x}$, for some constant $a$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: think of the exponential function.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)=c*e^{-x}$ Is one and maybe the only solution.Try to solve it like $f(x)+f^{'}(x)=0$, than it can be seen more clearly.